# Parse a date-time string in ISO 8601 format without offset-from-UTC

Tags: android, date

I am parsing date of string type into Date format , but everytime got this exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-05-21T00:00:00" (at offset 4)
```

My code is :

```
   String d = "2016-05-21T00:00:00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = df.parse(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730298/java-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Comment: Your `SimpleDateFormat` that you're using to parse doesn't understand your input string - the formats don't match. Simply fix it so your parser matches the input format.  As a note, your input string format is almost [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format

Comment: i am wondering... why is it *almost* the same? Can the input be changed so it *is* the same? There's no value in *almost* using a standard...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your date string and DateFormat need to match. For your input `"2016-05-21T00:00:00"`, the correct DateFormat is:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-05-21T00:00:00" )
```

## ISO 8601

The input string `2016-05-21T00:00:00` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when parsing or generating textual representations of date-time values.

The input string lacks any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) info. So the string by itself is imprecise, has no specific meaning as it is not a moment on the timeline. Such values are represented in java.time by the [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class.

```
String input = "2016-05-21T00:00:00";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

If you know from a larger context that the string is intended to have meaning for a certain offset-from-UTC, assign a [`ZoneOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of( 5 , 30 );
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( zoneOffet );
```

Even better, if you are certain of an intended time zone, specify a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
String expectedDateFormat=getDateFromString("2016-05-21 00:00:00","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss","yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss");
```

This method will perform actual format to expected format.

```
public static String getDateFromString(String dateInString, String actualformat, String exceptedFormat) {
        SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat(actualformat);

        String formatedDate = null;
        Date date;
        try {
            date = form.parse(dateInString);
            SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat(exceptedFormat);
            formatedDate = postFormater.format(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return formatedDate;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public  class test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // ref http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
           SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss");
          System.out.println("Current Date: " + simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }

}
```

for more information on [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score -3):

try this way

```
String d = "2016-05-21 00:00:00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = df.parse(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**EDIT**

```
String d = "2016-05-21 00:00:00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date myDate = null;
    try {
        myDate = df.parse(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-05-21 00:00:00" (at offset 4)

Comment: @Touchstone developer whats ur targetSdk?

Comment: targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: @Touchstone developer There are some changes made for 23 check out [this](http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/android-marshmallow-and-simpledateformat)

Comment: @Touchstonedeveloper: see my edit post it will defenatly work

Comment: @Touchstone developer anytime :)