# Android Extract from strings in arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist

I have this problem, where I want to extract some data out of an `arraylist`. My `arraylist` looks like this:

```
List<String> allDate_time = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What my code is doing with this `arraylist`, is that I pull some data out of `JSON` and I store it in this `arraylist`. As you can see here:

```
JSONObject date_timeArray = json2.getJSONObject( 0 );

String date_time = date_timeArray.getString( "date_time" );

allDate_time.add( date_time );
```

What I'm receiving when I try to pull data out of the `arraylist`, by doing this:

```
dateView = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.dateTX );

dateView.setText( allDate_time.get( 0 ) );
```

Then I get a value like this which looks like this:

`2018-03-18T01:39:45+01:00`

Is there anyway, that I can extract only the date? So that when I `setText`, the value will only be

`2018-03-18`

And then, I can make another call `setText` giving me the value of time:

`01:39:45`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a date-time string in ISO 8601 format without offset-from-UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649735/parse-a-date-time-string-in-iso-8601-format-without-offset-from-utc)