# yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `datetime` in `9/9/2017 8:25:02 PM` `format` and I need output in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ` format in SQL.

Also need the timezone as well like: `-05:00` or `+05:50`

e.g.
`dateTime`:  `2016-02-02T12:44:18.7832703Z`
`timezone`:  `-06:00`

Comment: `DATETIME` doesn't have a "format."  Are you storing them as `VARCHAR`?  Also, what timezone has `+05:50`...?

Comment: A quick Google search for "SQL Server format date" shows some options and examples for converting and formatting values when selecting from the data.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Siyual I don't know which one is +5:50 but there are some odd ones. Like Newfoundland that is -3:30. My guess is the OP mean :30 and typed :50 for the half hour. :)

Comment: How to convert 2/2/2017 12:44:18 PM into 2016-02-02T12:44:18.7832703Z

Answer (score 0):

For the timezone you should use [DateTimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql) and not Datetime.

For the format of the string you have to use one of the predefined formats in SQL
for example:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(50), dateoff (Column containing the DatetimeOffset), 127)
```

Comment: What is dateoff? That is not a valid t-sql function.

Comment: How to convert 2/2/2017 12:44:18 PM into 2016-02-02T12:44:18.7832703Z.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert SQL Server date format to Java date format

You can try Java to see [Java format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730298/java-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

The closest in the SQL that is possible is using the TODATETIMEOFFSET, the problem of this function is that you need to know the time zone of the date

```
DECLARE @Timezone int = Datediff(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(),getdate())
SELECT  CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0), TODATETIMEOFFSET (convert(datetime, '2/2/2017 12:44:18 PM'),@Timezone),127) [datetimeoffset(0)], Convert(varchar(50),  
TODATETIMEOFFSET (convert(datetime, '2/2/2017 12:44:18 PM'),@Timezone),127)[datetime]


datetimeoffset(0)                  datetime
---------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
2017-02-02 12:44:18 -04:00         2017-02-02T16:44:18Z
```

[TODATETIMEOFFSET (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/todatetimeoffset-transact-sql)

[AT TIME ZONE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql)

[Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql)

Comment: How to convert 2/2/2017 12:44:18 PM into 2016-02-02T12:44:18.7832703Z

Comment: There is no way to convert SQL Server date format to Java date format

Answer (score 0):

The answers here were right but they didn't give a clear answer to your exact case.

You could convert it this way:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET(4), N'2016-02-02T12:44:18.7832703Z');
```

Read more about [DatetimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).