# Parse String datetime with Zone with Java Date

Tags: java, date

I am trying to parse these dates in `java.time` and then get a `String` representation.

```
2021-12-27T09:15:09.738+02:00
2022-01-11T20:04:21+02:00
```

I read this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058212/2594961) and I have created a method in order to parse the above dates and return a `String` with the desired format:

```
public String getDatetimeFromDatetimeWithT(String dateFull) {
    String date = "";
    
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFull, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
        date = ldate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(dateFull + " not matched 1 " + e);
    }

    try {
        LocalDateTime ldate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFull, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));
        date = ldate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(dateFull + " not matched 2" + e);
    }
    
    return date;
}
```

However, none patterns are matched. What I am missing here?

UPDATE: In both dates I get an exception for the `+` character.

```
2021-12-27T09:15:09.738+02:00 not matched 1 java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-12-27T09:15:09.738+02:00' could not be parsed at index 23

2022-01-11T20:04:21+02:00 not matched 2 java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-01-11T20:04:21+02:00' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Comment: You are using an OffsetDateTime representation where a ZonedDateTime might be assumed. Use ZonedDateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to define a pattern, your examples are ISO formatted and **they contain an offset rather than a zone**.

That's why you can use this alternative (if you want to stick to `LocalDateTime`):

```
// parse without passing a formatter
OffsetDateTime odtA = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-12-27T09:15:09.738+02:00");
OffsetDateTime odtB = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-01-11T20:04:21+02:00");
// extract the LocalDateTimes
LocalDateTime ldtA = odtA.toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime ldtB = odtB.toLocalDateTime();
// print them
System.out.println(ldtA);
System.out.println(ldtB);
```

Result:

```
2021-12-27T09:15:09.738
2022-01-11T20:04:21
```

To make your method shorter, write something like this:

```
public static String getDatetimeFromDatetimeWithT(String dateFull) throws DateTimeParseException {
    return OffsetDateTime.parse(dateFull)
                         .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
}
```

This basically parses the `String` argument to an `OffsetDateTime` and formats that `OffsetDateTime` using only the information a `LocalDateTime` has.

Result stays the same as posted above…

Answer (score 1):

Your date pattern is not correct.
Use this:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX
```

Or use one of the predefined [ISO](https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001437-13/reference/r_iso_8601_date_format.htm) standard classes to do the parsing for you:

```java
DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.parse(dateFull);
```

Comment: Could you write how to use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.parse(dateFull);` ? I tried to replace it in ` LocalDateTime ldate = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFull, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"));` but it isn't valid.

Comment: What date string are you using? Because it works in my test environment.

Comment: You can't use LocalDateTime as it doesn't track the time zone. You need to use ZonedDateTime or  OffsetDateTime. (See my answer)

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime doesn't contain time zone info. For that you need to use either ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime class. You still can (and should IMHO) use DateTimeFormatter. There is predefined formatter there called ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME that should fit your needs. Also a while ago I needed to parse a date from a string when format was not known in advance. So, I wrote an article about my implementation idea. You can read it [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)