# Convert date like 2017-03-25T11:24:20 to week day

Tags: java, date, kotlin

I have date strings in a given matching format: 2017-03-25T11:24:20 or 2020-06-26T11:14:00

and would like to find which day of the week is on a given date, usin java or Kotlin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz to yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730298/java-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the datetime string to `LocalDateTime` object and use its `getDayOfWeek()` method ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getDayOfWeek--)) to find the day of week, which returns a `DayOfWeek` enum ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)). In Kotlin, it would look like

```
val date = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-03-25T11:24:20")
println(date.dayOfWeek) // would print "SATURDAY"
```

On the `DayOfWeek` enum, you could use `getDisplayName(TextStyle style, Locale locale)` to get a localized textual representation, such as 'Mon' or 'Friday', or `getValue()` to get the day-of-week int value.